# How can I add a directory in an SFX Archive file through the command line?

Tags: command-line, rar

I want to create a folder in a RAR file and then add a file inside that folder. What commands should be issued to create a structure as follows?

```
File.exe(SFX Archive) > Folder > File.txt
```

I am trying to use this command:

```
rar a -ep1 -sfx rar.exe/folder file.txt
```

However it does not work and says that rar.exe/folder not found. The help file does not show a way to add a folder or directory inside an archive.

Comment: Which RAR utility do you currently use on your system?  Or do you currently have one?

Comment: WinRAR and am using Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the sfx switch, because you are adding to an existing SFX archive.  Thus your command should be along the lines of:

```
rar a -ep1 file.exe file_or_folder_to_add
```

Where file.exe is your existing SFX archive and the last parameter is the path to the file or directory you wish to add.

Comment: I want to add the file present in my current folder but I want to put that file in Cody Folder inside the RAR Archive. Using the above mentioned command I'll be able to make the directory structure which will be the same as the place from where I copy and not a new folder structure inside the Archive File.

Comment: Suppose I want to create the directory structure as: File.exe > Folder > Folder 1 > File.txt and I want to push the file located in my current folder so according to your method it won't create any folder inside the archive file.

Comment: You then must up the -ap switch.  Thus the way to do what you want would be `rar a -ep1 -ap"Folder\Folder 1\" File.exe File.txt`.  Note there is no space after the -ap option.

Comment: Thanks it worked, didn't get any example earlier to understand its usage.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution: you should use the `-ep1 -ap\FolderYouWant` parameter. This creates a folder called **FolderYouWant** inside the rar archive and put the files you determined in it.